# Laravel 5.8 Custom Form Request not working as intended?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-request

I created a custom form request named `ClientStoreRequest` with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ClientStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
        // return  $this->user()->can('add-clients');
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:clients|max:255',
            'website' => 'required|url',
            'street' => 'required',
            'town' => 'required',
            'postcode' => 'required|max:8',
            'county' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

I then modified my `ClientController`'s `store` method to look like this:

```
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  ClientStoreRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(ClientStoreRequest $request)
    {
        dd(1);
    }
```

So when the form is submitted, it should kill the page and print a `1` to the screen. When I use `ClientStoreRequest $request`, it just sends me back to the page where I submitted the form with no errors and no `dd(1)` result, however when I utilise `Request $request` it prints `1` to the screen.

Am I missing something really obvious? I've [followed the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) to make this.

Edit: I'm using a resource controller so the route is `Route::resource('clients', 'ClientController');`

Comment: How is your route set?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation >> When you define rules for your request, your controller function will not be touched as it is not allowed to run it due to your rules. Do you send all the required parameters?

Comment: @RobBiermann I'm not sure what you mean, I'll post the route now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit embarrassing but this one was purely down to developer error. The custom form request is actually working correctly... just my rules are referencing one field that I forgot to put into my form so isn't showing the errors to the screen! Once I echoed the usual $errors array I could see my error - I'll blame the late night coding!

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"..... And I forgot to put `name=""` attribute, making the rules is not working..